# Elección aleatoria de opciones en una tupla no funcionando

Tags: python, variables, algoritmos, optimización

Estoy trabajando en un programa que asigne los horarios para todos los empleados de un cine con python, he estado usando la ayuda de ChatGPT para escribir el código pero me tope con un problema que no estoy pudiendo solucionar:

El código funciona correctamente, se imprimen los horarios semanales para todos los empleados ya sean de tiempo completo o parcial, y se les asigna sus correspondientes días libres a cada uno. Pero parece estar fallando la seleccion aleatoria de los horarios por dia a cada empleado, ya que cuando ejecuto el codigo, en cada dia de la semana se imprimen todos los posibles horarios para cada empleado en lugar de uno sólo como debería ser, a continuación mostraré el código completo:

```
from pulp import LpVariable, LpProblem, LpMaximize, LpBinary, LpStatus, lpSum
import random


# Definir empleados y sus características
empleados_full_time = [
("Peña, Leon", "VENTAS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
("Quevedo, Juan Jose", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
("Morandin, Jeremias", "VENTAS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Rivera, Laura", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
("Heredia, Cristian", "SERVICIOS", ["Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
("Lopez, Gabriel", "SERVICIOS", ["Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
# Agrega aquí más empleados a tiempo completo
]

empleados_part_time = [
("Guzman, Roxana", "SERVICIOS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Guevara, Dario", "SERVICIOS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Ortiz, Victoria", "SERVICIOS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Duarte, Emmanuel", "SERVICIOS", ["Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
("Parmiggiani, Atilio", "SERVICIOS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
("Cisterna, Ivo", "SERVICIOS", ["Intermedio", "Cierre"]),
("Sayaverdi, Natalia", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
("Molinari, Belen", "VENTAS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Rivarola, Martina", "VENTAS", ["Apertura", "Intermedio"]),
("Maggi, Angela", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
("Marquez, Martina", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
("Lencina, Enzo", "VENTAS", ["Intermedio"]),
# Agrega aquí más empleados a tiempo parcial
]

# Definir días laborales y horarios disponibles
dias_laborales = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"]
horarios_disponibles = {
"Apertura": ["09:00 - 17:00", "09:30 - 17:30", "11:00 - 19:00", "11:30 - 19:30"],
"Intermedio": ["15:00 - 23:00", "15:30 - 23:30"],
"Cierre": ["16:30 - 00:30"]
}

# Crear el problema de asignación de horarios
problema = LpProblem("AsignacionHorarios", LpMaximize)
horario = LpVariable.dicts("Horario", ((empleado[0], dia, turno) for empleado in 
(empleados_full_time + empleados_part_time) for dia in dias_laborales for turno in 
horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]), cat=LpBinary)

# Restricción para que cada empleado tenga exactamente un turno en sus días laborales
for empleado in empleados_full_time + empleados_part_time:
problema += lpSum(horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] for dia in dias_laborales for turno in 
horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]) == 1

# Restricciones para empleados FULL TIME
for empleado in empleados_full_time:
dia_libre = dias_libres_full_time.get(empleado[0], random.choice(dias_laborales))

for dia in dias_laborales:
    # Si es el día libre, se asegura que no haya horarios asignados
    if dia == dia_libre:
        for turno in horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]:
            horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] = 0
    else:
        # Restricción para asignar solo un horario por día
        problema += lpSum(horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] for turno in 
horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]) <= 1

# Restricciones para empleados PART TIME
for empleado in empleados_part_time:
# Asignar cuatro días libres aleatorios
dias_libres = random.sample(dias_laborales, 4)
for dia in dias_laborales:
    for turno in horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]:
        if dia in dias_libres:
            horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] = 0  # Día libre
        else:
            problema += horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] <= 1  # Restricción para asignar solo 
un horario

# Resolver el problema
problema.solve()

# Imprimir horarios
for empleado in empleados_full_time + empleados_part_time:
print(f"Horario para {empleado[0]} (Área: {empleado[1]}):")
for dia in dias_laborales:
    print(f"{dia}: ", end="")
    has_schedule = False
    for turno in horarios_disponibles[empleado[2][0]]:
        if horario[empleado[0], dia, turno] == 1:
            print(f"{turno}", end=" ")
            has_schedule = True
    if not has_schedule:
        print("OFF", end="")
    print()

print("Estado de resolución:", LpStatus[problema.status])
```

**y el resultado que estoy obteniendo es el siguiente:**

```
Horario para Peña, Leon (Área: VENTAS):
Lunes: OFF
Martes: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Miércoles: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Jueves: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Viernes: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Sábado: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Domingo: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Horario para Quevedo, Juan Jose (Área: VENTAS):
Lunes: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30 
Martes: OFF
Miércoles: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30 
Jueves: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30 
Viernes: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30 
Sábado: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30 
Domingo: 15:00 - 23:00 15:30 - 23:30
```

**y así sucesivamente con el resto de los empleados, aquí un ejemplo de como me imprime los horarios de un empleado PART TIME:**

```
Horario para Guzman, Roxana (Área: SERVICIOS):
Lunes: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Martes: OFF
Miércoles: OFF
Jueves: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Viernes: OFF
Sábado: 09:00 - 17:00 09:30 - 17:30 11:00 - 19:00 11:30 - 19:30 
Domingo: OFF
```